# Help: Amortization irregular deposit math problem.

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

A loan is to be amortized by semi-annual payments of \$5,700 each with the interest at 15% compounded semi-annually. If the outstanding balance at the end of 6 years is \$78,890.24. 
A) Find the original amount borrowed.
B) How may regular semi-annual payments are needed?

I can't solve it because I have no idea whats the " n(r) " in the formula

Comment: Have you looked up the formula in your textbook?

Comment: Can you include the formula here?